# Correct way to set configuration properties with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, hive, sqlalchemy

I have a script that performs some ETL on a Hive cluster using [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) and SQLAlchemy. A portion of my job looks like this:

```
hivecon = hive_engine.raw_connection()
hivecur = hivecon.cursor()

...

hivecur.execute(""" <some query> """)
hivecur.execute(""" set hive.tez.container.size=5120 """)
hivecur.execute(""" <some other query> """)
```

My last query fails, and looking at the logs I've determined that the container size is never set properly. Is there a better way to change the session variables on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the correct way is to use `connect_args`:

Found [here](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#passing-session-configuration):

```
create_engine(
    'hive://user@host:10000/database',
    connect_args={'configuration': {'hive.exec.reducers.max': '123'}},
)
```

There's a corresponding `configuration` directive for DB-API connections.